# call function of other component on event in one component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, input, angular6, keyup

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have a component **HeaderComponent** whose html contain an input field like

**header.component.html**

```
<form>
    <input (keyup)="search($event)">
</form>

<app-search-result-card *ngIf="searchQuery.length > 3"
                          [searchQuery]="searchQuery">
</app-search-result-card>
```

**SearchResultComponent** has a function to perform search

```
export class SearchResultCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() searchQuery: string;
  searching = true;

  constructor(
    private searchService: SearchService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.performSearch();
  }

  /**
   * Perform search
   */
  performSearch() {
    this.searching = true;
    console.log(this.searchQuery);
    this.searching = false;
  }
}
```

**How can I call the function `performSearch` on the change in `searchQuery` value on `keyup` in the input field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use binding in your form using ngModel directive

```
<form>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" name="searchQuery">
</form>

<search [searchQuery]="searchQuery"></search>
```

In Header Component make searchQuery as empty string

```
searchQuery:string = ''
```

In your search component use lifecycle hook ngOnChanges to detect the input property changes or you can use propety setter. In ngOnChanges life cycle you will get searchQuery property value. In there you can perform search function

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnChanges  {
  searching: boolean
  @Input() searchQuery: string;


  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
    if(changes.searchQuery.currentValue.length > 3){
      this.performSearch()
    }
  }

   performSearch() {
    this.searching = true;
    console.log(this.searchQuery);
    this.searching = false;
  }
}
```

demo [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvzueg)

Answer (score 1):

Use `output` event binding for the same

```
<app-search-result-card *ngIf="searchQuery.length > 3"
                          [searchQuery]="searchQuery"
                          (queryResult)='queryResult($event)'>
</app-search-result-card>
```

Comment: Where to define `queryResult()` in **header component** or **search-result component**?

Comment: in header component

Answer (score 0):

header.component.ts

```
// use ViewChild to get instance of SearchResultCardComponent in template
@ViewChild(SearchResultCardComponent) src: SearchResultCardComponent;

search(event) {
  this.src.performSearch();
}
```

here how you can call child method in parent, but I suggest you refactor you component, make SearchResultCardComponent component dummy, receive only search result from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `SearchResultCardComponent` to `HeaderComponent` and call its function `performSearch()` when `searchKey.length > 3` as below:

In your `HeaderComponent.ts`,

```
constructor(private searchResultCardComponent: SearchResultCardComponent){}

search(searchKey: string) {
    if(searchKey.length <= 3) return;
    let searchResult = this.searchResultCardComponent.performSearch(searchKey);
}
```