# Call function of one component every time a set of values change in another component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of dropdowns and sliders which are implemented in one component. And I have a neural net visualization in another component. I pass 6 of the values obtained from several sliders and dropdowns to the neural net component via a service as it needs that data to draw the neural net. So what I want to do is from the values that I'm sending, every time the user changes the value of at least one drop down or slider I want to call the draw function to draw the neural net with the latest set of values. How can I do this in angular 7? I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827707/call-function-of-other-component-on-event-in-one-component-in-angular-6) but it is not what I need. I need the same function to fire if when each required drop downs or slider change its value.

shown below is a sample of my ui component, every time each of these changes I want to call a function in another component:

```
<div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Hidden Layers<br>
              <select [(ngModel)]="hiddenlayer" (change)="selecHiddenLayers($event.target.value);">
                    <option value=0>0</option>  
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                  <option value=2>2</option>
                  <option value=3>3</option>
              </select>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="hidden1" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Hidden Layer1 Nodes<br>
            <select (change)="selecHidden1Nodes($event.target.value);">
                <option value=1>0</option> 
                <option value=1>1</option>
                <option value=2>2</option>
                <option value=3>3</option>
                <option value=3>4</option>
                <option value=3>5</option>
            </select>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="hidden2" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Hidden Layer2 Nodes<br>
            <select (change)="selecHidden2Nodes($event.target.value);"> 
                <option value=1>0</option> 
                <option value=1>1</option>
                <option value=2>2</option>
                <option value=3>3</option>
                <option value=3>4</option>
                <option value=3>5</option>
            </select>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="hidden3" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Hidden Layer3 Nodes<br>
            <select (change)="selecHidden3Nodes($event.target.value);">  
                <option value=1>0</option> 
                <option value=1>1</option>
                <option value=2>2</option>
                <option value=3>3</option>
                <option value=3>4</option>
                <option value=3>5</option>
            </select>
        </a>
```

Shown below is the component that has the function I need to call. The function I need to call is the "draw()" function:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {select,schemeCategory10,scaleOrdinal} from 'd3';
import { NnConfigService } from '../../services/nn-config.service';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-neuralcanvas',
  templateUrl: './neuralcanvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./neuralcanvas.component.css']
})
export class NeuralcanvasComponent implements OnInit {

inputLayerHeight;
outputLayerHeight;
hiddenLayersDepths;
hiddenLayersCount;
nodeSize = 17;
width :any = 500 ;
height = 400;
hidden1Nodes;
hidden2Nodes;
hidden3Nodes;

  constructor(private nnService:NnConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nnService.currenthiddenlayers.subscribe(hidden => this.hiddenLayersCount = hidden);
      this.nnService.currenthidden1Nodes.subscribe(h1 => this.hidden1Nodes =h1 );
      this.nnService.currenthidden2Nodes.subscribe(h2 => this.hidden2Nodes=h2);
      this.nnService.currenthidden3Nodes.subscribe(h3 => this.hidden3Nodes=h3);
      this.nnService.currentoutputNodes.subscribe(out => this.outputLayerHeight=out);
      this.nnService.currentnnNodes.subscribe(nn => this.inputLayerHeight = nn); 
      this.hiddenLayersDepths = [this.hidden1Nodes,this.hidden2Nodes,this.hidden3Nodes]

    this.draw()
  }



  draw() {}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From the limited code supplied, it appears that you are already subscribing to the data changes and updating the component data.. is that correct?

e.g.:

```
this.nnService.currenthidden1Nodes.subscribe(h1 => this.hidden1Nodes =h1 );
```

If so, all you need to so is call the draw() method inside of the subscription:

```
this.nnService.currenthidden1Nodes.subscribe(h1 => {this.hidden1Nodes =h1; this.draw(); } );
```

Comment: draw function is in another component

Comment: From the code you have supplied, here's what I understand:

You have a UiComponent and a NeuralcanvasComponent (with a draw() function) and a NnConfigService.

1) You update the UiComponent's slider, which calls the NnConfigService.
2) The NeuralcanvasComponent is subscribed to the NnConfigService and so it receives the updated values and assignes the local variables (e.g. hidden1Nodes) 

And you want to call the draw() function when the slider values change?

Is that the case? If so, then the suggestion I made should work. If not, let me know what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

If the atual element is a component children, you could emit an event to parent component.
See: [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)